Weighted Random Sampling by Group Variable in Excel?
I am trying to figure out how to randomly sample IDs matching a group variable, but specifically randomly sampling by weighting each grouping variable. For instance, take this data:

I want to weight Group A at 60%, Group B at 20%, Group C at 15%, and Group D at 5%, and then randomly sample 10 IDs, without duplicates, according to those weights, returning those IDs in another column.
Hopefully this makes sense and thank you for any help in advance!
I have figured out random sampling generally but am struggling with the weighting and not sampling duplicates.

You could use the following:
=LET(a,{"A";"B";"C";"D"},
     b,{60;20;15;5},
     c,TOCOL(IFS(SEQUENCE(,SUM(b))<=LOOKUP(B2:B25,HSTACK(a,b)),A2:A25),2),
TAKE(UNIQUE(SORTBY(c,RANDARRAY(ROWS(c)))),10))

It first declares a to be your groups and it's weight b.
c looks up the values in column B in array a and returns it's weight b. If the returned value is smaller than or equal to the sequence of the sum of b it returns the value of column A, else it returns an error. This results in the values of column A being repeated the number of times mentioned in b where the value in column B matches the value of a.
TOCOL removes the errors and makes all values become a one column array.
This is sorted randomly and the first 10 values of the uniques are taken.

Hi P.b, this formula is nearly perfect! However, this formula returns duplicate ID values. Is there an argument I can add to the formula to only return an ID once? Thank you so much for your help!

Added UNIQUE to the last calc. part
